# Aggregating multiple subtotals?

Tags: r, reshape2

Is there a way to aggregate multiple sub-totals with `reshape2`?  E.g. for the airquality dataset

```
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
names(airquality) <- tolower(names(airquality))
aqm <- melt(airquality, id=c("month", "day"), na.rm=TRUE)
aqm <- subset(aqm, month %in% 5:6 & day %in% 1:7)
```

I can make a subtotal column for each month, that has the average for all variables within that month:

```
dcast(aqm, day ~ month+variable, mean, margins = "variable")
  day 5_ozone 5_solar.r 5_wind 5_temp 5_(all) 6_ozone 6_solar.r
1   1      41       190    7.4     67  76.350     NaN       286
2   2      36       118    8.0     72  58.500     NaN       287
3   3      12       149   12.6     74  61.900     NaN       242
4   4      18       313   11.5     62 101.125     NaN       186
5   5     NaN       NaN   14.3     56  35.150     NaN       220
6   6      28       NaN   14.9     66  36.300     NaN       264
7   7      23       299    8.6     65  98.900      29       127
  6_wind 6_temp   6_(all)
1    8.6     78 124.20000
2    9.7     74 123.56667
3   16.1     67 108.36667
4    9.2     84  93.06667
5    8.6     85 104.53333
6   14.3     79 119.10000
7    9.7     82  61.92500
```

I can also make a subtotal column for each variable, that has the average for all months within that variable:

```
dcast(aqm, day ~ variable+month, mean, margins = "month")
  day ozone_5 ozone_6 ozone_(all) solar.r_5 solar.r_6 solar.r_(all)
1   1      41     NaN          41       190       286         238.0
2   2      36     NaN          36       118       287         202.5
3   3      12     NaN          12       149       242         195.5
4   4      18     NaN          18       313       186         249.5
5   5     NaN     NaN         NaN       NaN       220         220.0
6   6      28     NaN          28       NaN       264         264.0
7   7      23      29          26       299       127         213.0
  wind_5 wind_6 wind_(all) temp_5 temp_6 temp_(all)
1    7.4    8.6       8.00     67     78       72.5
2    8.0    9.7       8.85     72     74       73.0
3   12.6   16.1      14.35     74     67       70.5
4   11.5    9.2      10.35     62     84       73.0
5   14.3    8.6      11.45     56     85       70.5
6   14.9   14.3      14.60     66     79       72.5
7    8.6    9.7       9.15     65     82       73.5
```

Is there a way to tell `reshape2` to calculate both sets of subtotals in one command? This command is close, adding in the grand total, but omits the monthly subtotals:

```
dcast(aqm, day ~ variable+month, mean, margins = c("variable", "month"))
```

Comment: There's some logic to this I can't remember, but you may be able to get what you want by changing the row and col vars: `dcast(aqm, month + day ~ variable, mean, margins = c("variable", "month"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you can use

```
acast(aqm, day ~ variable ~ month, mean, margins = c("variable", "month"))[,,'(all)']
```

The `acast` gets you the summary for each day over each variable over each month. The total aggregate "slice" ([,,'(all)']) has a row for each day, with a column for each variable (averaged over all months) and a '(all)' column averaging each day, over all variables over all months.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: I like it.  It still needs a little work to convert it from a 3D array to a data.frame, but it's got the various sub-totals I want to calculate.

Comment: Using `plyr` should work to get it as a dataframe. Assign the acast to `array3D` and try the following code. Does it work?

`library(plyr); adply(.data=array3D, .margins=3)`